# How are computed the confidence intervals of emmeans when adjusted with Tukey method?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, emmeans

I have troubles to get back to the "CL" values given by the emmeans package.

My first goal was to perform a kind of power study : I am working on plants and I want to see how much I can improve my experimental design for next season to have more significant differences between my genotypes. My genotypes are repeated and this is used as a blocking factor.
I want to play with the number of repetitions (assuming that the means and the residual SE would remain the same). In the end I want to find a compromise between budget issues and statistical power.

I was thinking to look at the confidence intervals (CIs), having in mind that if the CIs of two genotypes cover at least one common value, the two genotypes are not significantly different. So I want to see how much I can reduce the CIs when playing with the number of repetitions.

My guess for the CIs calculations using Tukey method for multiple comparisons is :

> μi ± (σ/(2*√(ni)))*q
>
> with μi being the mean for the i-th genotype
>
> ni the number of observations for the i-th genotype,
>
> σ the residual standard error and
>
> q the studentized range statistics with t (the number of genotypes) and dfE (the degrees of freedom of the residual) as argument for α = 0.05

Which is equivalent to :

> μi ± (SEi*q)/2
>
> with SEi being the standard error of the i-th genotype

Here is a small example dataset with 6 genotypes and 3 repetitions and the code I ran :

```
library(emmeans)

# import DF
df <- structure(list(Geno = structure(c(6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
                                     4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L),
                                   .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                                   class = "factor"), variable = c(2.279628571, 3.925157143, 3.089, 2.26, 2.503,
                                                                   2.495114286, 2.867166667, 3.069238095, 3.884285714, 3.409595238, 
                                                                   3.710714286, 1.763142857, 2.865285714, 4.219214286, 3.263452381, 
                                                                   3.359428571, 2.335285714, 2.443), 
                 Rep = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                                 .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Geno", "variable", "Rep"),
            row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame")

# Number of observation
N <- nrow(df)

# Number of treatments
t <- nlevels(df$Geno)

# Define the model
model <- lm(data=df, variable ~ Geno + Rep)

# Compute means and confidence intervals
E_means <- as.data.frame(emmeans(model, pairwise~Geno)$emmean)

# Extract Standard Errors
se <- E_means[,"SE"]

# Studentized range statistic
q <- qtukey(0.95, nmeans=t, df=E_means[,"df"])

expected_CI <- se*q/2
emmeans_CI <- ((E_means[,"upper.CL"] - E_means[,"lower.CL"])/2)

print(expected_CI)
print(emmeans_CI)
```

Note that most of the time I am dealing with unbalanced data (so I have different SE for each genotype). I want first to make it clear for a simple (= balanced) case.

expected_CI and emmeans_CI are always different for every test I have done so far (not very much different, but still different) so I guess I am not doing the calculation the same way than the emmeans package. So here is my question : how is it done in the emmeans package ?

Any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are confounding EMMs with *differences* of EMMs. Moreover, the formulas you are using apply only to *balanced* one-way designs.

With your example, if you will try:

```
emm <- emmeans(model, pairwise ~ Geno)
```

and then do:

```
confint(emm$emmeans, adjust = "tukey")
confint(emm$contrasts, adjust = "tukey")
```

you will notice a few things. First, the CIs for the EMMs themselves don't use the specified Tukey adjustment (it replaces it with Sidak), because that adjustment is only suitable for pairwise comparisons. Second, the two summaries have different numbers of results (except when there are exactly 3 treatments) and different standard errors. For example, with 4 treatments, there are 4 EMMs but 6 pairwise comparisons; and with an unbalanced design, there may be 6 different SEs associated with those comparisons.

If you want to understand the Tukey adjustment for pairwise comparisons, you need to use the statistics appropriate to the pairwise comparisons -- that second summary. The Tukey-adjusted CIs use the estimated differences plus or minus `sqrt(0.5*qtukey(.95, nmeans, df)) * SE`, where the `SE`s come from the results for pairwise differences.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I wrongly assumed that it was the Tukey adjustment used for the CIs of EMMs, as it was consistent (at least for this example) with the groups displayed by the `cld` function that I usually run afterwards and that displays the same CIs than the `emm$emmeans` table. I tried to change a value for the E genotype (`df[16,2] <- 3.37`) and it's not consistent anymore for the E-F comparison.
Do you have any idea of what are those CIs of `emm$emmeans`? It does not match the CIs of `confint(emm$emmeans, adjust = "tukey")` so I guess they are unadjusted so computed with student?

Comment: Regarding the CIs of pairwise comparisons, the ones I am really interested in, I think the right formula to use is `sqrt(0.5)*qtukey(.95, nmeans, df) * SE` and then it is consistent with the CIs given by `confint(emm$contrasts, adjust = "tukey")`

Comment: The annotations at the ends of the outputs always say what adjustment was made. If it doesn’t say, there is no adjustment.